# Postgres Exporter and Connection to Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql

I have postgres exporter installed , after executing I get the below error in the logs

`time="2020-02-28T08:45:42Z" level=error msg="Error opening connection to database (postgresql://ossdb01db:PASSWORD_REMOVED@dop-postgres:6432/paasdb?sslmode=disable): pq: password authentication failed for user \"ossdb01db\"" source="postgres_exporter.go:1474"`

Postgres DB is working fine also.
I have tried to search in google about the issue ,but couldn't find and solution.
Can anyone help ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is this "postgres exporter"?

Comment: This is a postgres exporter :) : https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-postgres-exporter

Comment: Perhaps raise an issue with the project.